# NodeJs Server flooded with UDP Broadcasts, doesn't send response

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, arduino, udp

I am building a system using an ESP8266/NodeMcu module (similar to an Arduino, just with networking capabilities) and a NodeJs server running on the local network.

To discover the IP address of the server, I'm trying to use UDP broadcasting on the NodeMcu module. The idea is to send out a message on the local broadcasting IP (e.g. 192.168.1.255). The server then receives the message and sends a response, confirming that it is the server. This way, the NodeMcu knows the direct address of the server for further communication.

The problem is, that the server is completely flooding itself with the same message whenever it receives the first message from the NodeMcu, while the NodeMcu actually sends out a message only once a second.

It looks like this on the NodeMcu side:

```
[UDP] Sending UDP Broadcast on IP: 192.168.43.255, Port: 8080, Message: ESP8266 UDP Server Discovery Broadcast
```

The server outputs something like this, many times a second:

```
[10:33:07] 127.0.0.1:8080 @ service discovery : ESP8266 UDP Server Discovery Broadcast
[10:33:07] 127.0.0.1:8080 @ service discovery : ESP8266 UDP Server Discovery Broadcast
[10:33:07] 127.0.0.1:8080 @ service discovery : ESP8266 UDP Server Discovery Broadcast
```

It doesn't make sense that it's receiving that many messages, especially because it's apparently coming from `127.0.0.1` and not the IP of the NodeMcu. It also doesn't send out any response.

I tried to receive the broadcast on my phone with a [UDP Monitor app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandersoft.udpmonitor), an application called [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/) and the Linux Terminal. It all worked fine, and sending a manual response triggered the acknowledgement on the NodeMcu.

So I'm thinking there has to be some kind of error with the server, or with the network I'm using. The server is running on Linux on my computer, while I'm hosting the network via a hotspot on my phone (my real WiFi network blocked UDP broadcasting). The Linux firewall is turned off.

I'm no expert in JavaScript or NodeJs by any means and the server was written by someone I'm working with, but he has no clue either. Anyway, this is the important part on the server:

```
client.on('listening', function () {
  var address = client.address();
  debugMessage(
    format('Service discovery running on port %s', config.port)
  );
  client.setBroadcast(true);
});

client.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
  debugMessage(
    format('%s:%s @ service discovery : %s', rinfo.address, rinfo.port, message)
  );
  client.send(message, 0, message.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.ip);
});

client.bind(config.port);
```

The code on the NodeMcu looks like this:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>        // WiFi library
#include <WiFiUdp.h>            // UPD functionality

// UDP variables
WiFiUDP udp;
unsigned int localUdpPort = 8080;
char incomingPacket[255];
const char broadcastMessage[] = "ESP8266 UDP Server Discovery Broadcast";

// Server details - written to when the server is found
IPAddress serverIp = ~WiFi.subnetMask() | WiFi.gatewayIP(); // Use Broadcast Address as default in case the UDP service discovery isn't working as intended
unsigned int serverPort = localUdpPort; // Use local port as default in case the UDP service discovery ins't working as intended

void setupWiFi()
{
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  #if LOGGING
  Serial.println("Connecting to network: " + (String) WIFI_SSID);
  #endif

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(100);
  }

  #if LOGGING
  Serial.print("Connected to network, Local IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  #endif

  udp.begin(localUdpPort); // begin listening on UDP port
  #if LOGGING
  Serial.printf("Now listening at IP %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), localUdpPort);
  #endif LOGGING
}

// Discover the server via a UDP broadcast, and store it's IP and Port in the local network in field variables for later use
// IMPORTANT - For the server to work, the Linux Firewall has to be disabled!!!
void discoverServer()
{
  changeColor(PURPLE, false); // change the color of the RGB status LED to signal that the program is searching for the server

  bool serverFound = false; // stop when the server is found

  IPAddress broadcastIp = ~WiFi.subnetMask() | WiFi.gatewayIP(); // Get the Broadcast IP of the local network (e.g. 192.168.0.255)

  while (!serverFound)
  {
    // Send UDP Broadcast
    udp.beginPacket(broadcastIp, localUdpPort);
    udp.write(broadcastMessage);
    udp.endPacket();

    #if LOGGING
    Serial.printf("[UDP] Sending UDP Broadcast on IP: %s, Port: %d, Message: %s\n", broadcastIp.toString().c_str(), localUdpPort, broadcastMessage);
    #endif

    delay(1000); // Pause a few milliseconds to avoid flooding the network

    // Receive UDP packets
    int packetSize = udp.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize > 0)
    {
      // Read incoming UDP Packet
      int len = udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
      if (len > 0)
      {
        incomingPacket[len] = 0;
      }

      #if LOGGING
      Serial.printf("[UDP] Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n", packetSize, udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), udp.remotePort());
      Serial.printf("[UDP] Packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);
      #endif

      // Check if the received message is from the server we are searching for
      if (strcmp(incomingPacket, broadcastMessage) == 0)
      {
        serverIp = udp.remoteIP();
        serverPort = udp.remotePort();

        #if LOGGING
        Serial.printf("[UDP] Found Server on IP: %s, Port: %d\n", serverIp.toString().c_str(), serverPort);
        #endif

        serverFound = true;
        changeColor(YELLOW, false); // Change status color of RGB LED back to yellow
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm really wondering if there is something wrong with the server, the network or the NodeMcu. Especially because every other method I tried worked perfectly, just not when I'm sending it from the NodeMcu. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an error in the server code.
Instead of

```
client.send(message, 0, message.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.ip);
```

it should have been

```
client.send(message, 0, message.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.address);
```

The server didn't know `rinfo.ip`, so it spammed itself with the same message over and over again.